I have used 'react-native-webview' but I can't use the 'Print' function of the web in webview. I checked on chrome and it works
I have used 'react-native-webview' but I can't use the 'Print' function of the web in webview. I checked on chrome and it works.
I want to Print on webview or do you have any solution to suggest me.
I think this only supports the web, mobile has to take care of itself.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
